# Bootstrap 4 scrollspy not working on a links than nav

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have divided my html in layers and the fourth layer is the menu of the site and the fifth layer is the area that contains the contents.

Here is the snippet

```html
<body>
  <main data-spy="scroll" data-target=".menu-list" data-offset="50">
    <div class="top-layer">
    </div>
    <div class="second-layer">
    </div>
    <div class="third-layer">
    </div>
    <div class="fourth-layer sticky-top">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <ul class="menu-list inline-list">
          <li class="">
            <a class="" href="#experiences">Experiences</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a class="" href="#education">Education</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a class="" href="#skills">Skills</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a class="" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a class="" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fifth-layer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content-area border" id="experiences">
        </div>
        //other divs with ids
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

I've added the `data-spy` in main tag that is scrollable. But it doesn't seem to work. I may have not gotten the concept of scrollspy completely but have been trying to figure it out why it is not working. Can anyone help me out with explanation?